# Establishing Relationships With Generics

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics

I am attempting to establish a type hierarchy between objects whose implementation would belong to one another. The syntax has become redundant, leading me to believe that I am either abusing generics, or that there are cleverer means of representing this sort of relationship between interfaces.

Let me give you an example:

```
interface Interface
{ }
interface Class<I>
    where I : Interface
{ }
interface Method<I, C>
    where I : Interface
    where C : Class<I>
{ }
interface Parameter<I, C, M>
    where I : Interface
    where C : Class<I>
    where M : Method<I, C>
{ }
```

}

The root of this hierarchy is the `Interface`. Then, we have a `Class` which may only be derived from a specific `Interface`.

The `Method` must belong to a specific implementation of a `Class`.

`Parameter` may only be implemented with specific `Method` implementation.

Is there a better way to go about this? I'm a little rusty with the C# generics syntax as I've been swimming in C and Go for the past year.

Comment: It really depends on how you want to use this.  Right now your question seems a little to generic, no pun intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to capture business rules of your business domain -- interfaces and classes and methods and parameters -- in the type system.

I suggest that you not try to do that. It tends to cause pain, because the rules of the type system do not necessarily map cleanly to the rules of your business domain.

In particular: business domains often have many rules of the form "an X is a kind of Y that is restricted from doing Z", and that is immediately difficult to represent in a type system that uses the Liskov Substitution Principle: that if a Y is a kind of X, and an X can do Z, then Y can be used in a context that requires a Z-doer.

Generics were designed to solve the problem of containers, comparers, monadic types (like nullable, sequence, future, lazy, and so on) and other *simple* type structures. My rule of thumb: if you can't use the word "of" in your description, or make a nice easy adjective, then don't use generics.  "Bowl of apples, bowl of oranges, ok, sounds like bowl is generic. Sequence of numbers, sequence of names, sure.  Nullable date, lazy string."  All of those are nice and easy.  Class of interfaces? not so clear.

More thoughts here:

https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: You are exactly correct. So the answer is, yes, I am abusing generics! The idea stemmed from using an IoC framework, such as Unity, to replace different parts of a proprietary system's implementation. However, you are correct in assuming that at some point the architecture attempted to capture business logic through generics, which was where the abuse began.